# A single generic solution?

Tags: c#, generics, nullable

I want to write a generic method along the following lines:

```
public IEnumerable<T> S<T> (List<T> source)
{
    //dosomething with source
    if (someCondition)
        yield return null;
    else
        yield return someNonNullItem;
}
```

T can be a value type (e.g. int), a nullable type (e.g. int?), or a ref type (e.g. string). In all the three cases, I want to have the ability to return a null value.

The //dosomething block is pretty generic, involves shifting things around, and can be used with all types with no modification. Similarly, the (someCondition) boolean check does not have any type dependency.

Some considerations:

1. I cannot use default(T) where T is a non-nullable value type (e.g. default(T) where T is int won't work). An explicit representation of null is required.
2. I don't want to convert from T to T? if I can avoid it since the source list can be quite long (millions of items).

At present, I'm stuck with having to write three functions, and one of them has to have a different name (because the type constraints are not deemed part of the method signature).  The three functions have identical bodies (not shown for brevity).

```
    public IEnumerable<T?> S<T>(List <T> source) where T:struct
    {
    }

    public IEnumerable<T?> S<T>(List <T?> source) where T : struct
    {
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> S4Ref<T>(List <T> source) where T : class
    {
    }
```

In the first two methods, I need the T:struct constraint to be able to return the Nullable.  In the third method: (a) I need a new name, S4Ref, to avoid clashing with the first method, and, (b) I need the T:class constraint to be able to return a null.

In reality, there are numerous such S methods I have to write, and if I follow the above approach, I'll have to write three versions for each of them.  I'll also turn them into extension methods for List

Questions:

1. Is there a way to have a single generic function that does this? Or at least reduce from 3 to 2 methods?
2. If not, what is the best way to eliminate duplication in the function bodies?

At present I'm veering towards using T4 templates to address this.

Comment: if `T` is `int` (**not** `int?`) you cant return `null`.

Comment: I'd strongly consider re-evaluating the design of yielding `null` values here in the first place, or at the very least, requiring the caller of the method to pass in a nullable type, leaving the conversion from non-nullable to nullable their responsibility.

Comment: I don't think you can get better than two methods - and that would basically be the `IEnumerable<T?>` one, and an `IEnumerable<T>` without a constraint on `T`. If that had a different name, would you "trust" your callers not to call it with a non-nullable value type?

Comment: You could potentially get away with giving the two methods the same name if you use a ghastly hack, btw. I really don't recommend it, but... http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/11/02/evil-code-overload-resolution-workaround/

Comment: It's times like this that I wish `Nullable` didn't require it's generic arguments to be value types.  If that were the case you could just wrap T in `Nullable` unconditionally, and you'd be fine.

Comment: @Servy: I need an explicit representation of a missing value in the output, so not yielding such representation does not seem like an option (unless I'm missing something?)

Comment: @Fenchurch You can represent it using something other than `null`.  That's the point.

Comment: Indeed, there's nothing to stop you creating an `Optional<T>` struct where `T` is unconstrained - then you can just have a single method returning an `IEnumerable<Optional<T>>`.

Comment: Templates are probably the way to go, after reading this more closely.  I suppose you could return object too.

Comment: I do not get it. What does your ideal code return for int when you want to return a null?

Comment: Your code is very confusing. The prototype says that it returns `IEnumerable<T>`, but the code inside returns a single value. Which is it?

Comment: @JimMischel you has missed `yield return` statement.

Comment: @JonSkeet FxCop will complain if you try and call it `Optional<T>`, as it clashes with a reserved word in other languages. We settled on `NonMandatory<T>` or `NonCompulsory<T>`, I forget which

Comment: @JimMischel: Sorry for the confusion. The pseudo code has a yield return, not just a return, so I think it's compatible with IEnumberable<T> (?)

Comment: @Fenchurch yes of course it is. Any way, reffering to `Optional<T>` - it could have overloaded cast operator in order to simplicity casting.

Comment: No, I did not miss the `yield return`. It's just unusual. Kind of like a `SingleOrDefault`, but returning a sequence of 1 rather than a single value. Why not have it return an empty sequence in place of a `null` value? That is, rather than `yield return null`, do a `yield  break`.

Answer (score 0):

You've set yourself up with conflicting constraints.  In the problem definition, you say you want a function that works on value types (i.e. int) but be able to return null without turning it into a nullable type. As a design paradigm, I don't expect a collection of things to include something that doesn't exist.  Yeah, I said that. To me, returning a null item means it doesn't exist, and yet you are returning null.  If the purpose of function S is to filter items, it would be better to skip the item that doesn't match and return the next one.

For example, a typical use of IEnumerable is code that looks like this:

```
    List<int> myList = ....  // somehow fill the list
    foreach(int element in S(myList))
    {
         // do something with the int element.  What should I expect to do with a null
         // even if you could return one?  The only thing I could reasonable do here is
         // skip it.  I have no idea which element of myList the null corresponds to

    }
```

in other words, even if the foreach look like this:

```
    foreach(int? element in S(myList))
```

I'm still stuck as to what to do with a null value for element.  There is still no context to know which element of myList caused a null from function S.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. To clarify: I don't want to convert input List<T> to List<T?> before processing it. The value becomes missing after the input is processed.